# SmartGit, unable to push, "remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied"

Tags: git, authentication, gitlab, push, smartgit

> remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied
>
> remote: You must use a personal access token with 'read_repository' or 'write_repository' scope for Git over HTTP.
>
> remote: You can generate one at https://gitlab.com/profile/personal_access_tokens

I've created Personal Access Tokens with all available scopes included and placed it in `Edit -> Preferences -> Hosting Providers` for the GitLab account, but I still can't push. The GitLab account has 2FA and I also have [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows) installed if it matters.

Windows 10 x64.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you have a credential helper installed, check if it is active:

```
cd C:\path\to\repo
git config credential.helper
```

If it returns "manager", open your [Windows Credentials Manager](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026814/windows-accessing-credential-manager) and check if credentials are already stored for gitlab.com.
If so, delete it, then push again: Git should ask for your credentials. Do enter your PAT (Personal Access Token) as password.

Comment: On that note, try logging in on the website. For me it's because of the 2FA. So signing in again didn't work.

Comment: Using a token instead of your account password should work, though.

Answer (score 2):

I was having similar issues trying to "git push" my changes from VS up to GitLab. After creating a personal access token I was able to successfully make a commit using the following steps:

1. Create a personalized access token in GitLab
2. In VS, I committed then entered "git push" in the terminal
3. Enter the username at the top of VS (should be prompted after hitting enter on step 2)
4. For password, copied and pasted the GitLab token I created earlier (from step 1)

Thank you @VonC !